# Probablity to get balls, such that has more than $n_\text{red}$ balls and $n_\text{blue}$ balls

Tags: probability

I have an urn that contains 6 red balls and 10 blues balls. Let $A$ be event randomly draw $8$  balls without replacement from that urn.

What is the probability of event $A$ so that the drawn balls greater or equal 3 red balls and greater or equal 4 blue balls from 8 balls?

Generally, I have $n_1$ red balls and $n_2$ blue balls in urn. Let draw $m$ balls. What is prob. such that in $m$ balls ($m=8$ in above case) has greater or equal $k_1$ red balls and greater or equal $k_2$ blue balls

Thank in advance

This is my solution what I done

We  drawn 8 balls without replacement from 10 balls in urn. The possible outcomes is $\dbinom{16}{8}$.

To guareente that the balls greater or equal 3 red balls and greater or equal 4 blue balls from 8 balls, we have set
$\Omega=\{(n_\text{red},n_\text{blue})| n_\text{red} \ge 3 \cap n_\text{blue} \ge 4 \cap n_\text{red}+n_\text{blue}=8\}$

UPDATE:
Based on answer of true blue anil. I would like to convert it to symbol. It will help anyone who is interesting in that problem

$$P[X]=\frac{\sum_{x=max(k_1,m-n_2)}^{min(n_1,m-k_2)} \dbinom{n_1}{x} \dbinom{n_2}{m-x}}{\dbinom{n}{m}}$$

Comment: The event could be seen as either you draw $3$ red and $5$ blue, or you draw $4$ red and $4$ blue.

Comment: If I understand well then there are $16$ balls in the urn (not $10$). What is the meaning of "even randomly"? I suspect that the balls have equal chances to be drawn. It is vague terminology for me.

Comment: Drawing $8$ without replacement from $6+10=16$ might suggest ${16 \choose 8}$ equally probable outcomes

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It must be 16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take care about spelling, else the question becomes incomprehensible.

Taking "even" to be a typo for "event"

$Pr =$ $\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{10}{5} + \dbinom{6}{4}\dbinom{10}{4}\over\dbinom{16}{8}$

*PS:*

Regarding the more general problem, I'll  put it in words for better understanding. You can then easily insert the symbols.

*Starting # for red balls:* Higher of{minimum red stipulation & (sample size - blue population)}

*Ending # for red balls:* Lower of{Red population & (sample size - minimum blue stipulation)}

Comment: It is good answer. +1. Could you see my update question, in which, I want to formula the above problem by mathematics. Thanks

Comment: Some advise avoiding commas, which can sometimes mean *and*, and sometimes,*or*, so $\Omega=\{(n_{red},n_{blue})| n_{red} \ge 3 \cap n_{blue} \ge 4 \cap( n_{red}+n_{blue}=8)\}$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How about find prob. in my second case, which represents by $m,n_1,n_2,k_1,k_2$? Thanks

Comment: You just have to sum up the probabilities of feasible combos subject to constraints just as we did with the numerical example. You should now be able to take this extra step.

Comment: Yes. However, to find the range of sum is more difficult for me. Could you help me to show it in your answer

Comment: Thank true blue anil. I updated it by your answer. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: I corrected it. Check it agian

Comment: Thanks agian. Could you explain to me how do you find the above range? Because  if I have another conditions, the range will be change. For example,  $\Omega=\{(n_\text{red} ,n_\text{blue} )|n_\text{red} \ge k_1\cup m \ge n_\text{red} +n_\text{blue} \}$

Comment: That is why instead of just writing symbols, I put it in words to show the logic. If you have a different question, and  can't tackle it, post it, showing your effort. Then someone or other may answer.